# Mostrar bandera según el idioma puesto

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Buenas estoy haciendo un selector de idioma, es la primera vez que trabajo con laravel.

La idea es que cuando seleccione el ingles salga la vandera seleccionada de ingles y cque haga lo mismo con la bandera española.

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right dropLang">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle-mio" data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
      <img src="images/lang/flag-es.png" />
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right coloDrop">
      <li class="active padDrop">
        <a href="{{ url('lang', ['es']) }}" class="aDrop">
          <img src="images/lang/flag-es.png" />
          <span class="marDrop">Español</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="padDrop">
        <a href="{{ url('lang', ['en']) }}" class="aDrop">
          <img src="images/lang/flag-uk.png" />
          <span class="marDrop">English</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Alguna sugerencia??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del helper [config()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-config).

Usa `config('app.locale')`, para obtener el actual lenguaje de la aplicación

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right dropLang">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle-mio" data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
      @if (config('app.locale') === 'es')
        <img src="images/lang/flag-es.png" />
      @elseif (config('app.locale') === 'en')
        <img src="images/lang/flag-uk.png" />
      @endif
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right coloDrop">
     <li class="active padDrop">
       <a href="{{ url('lang', ['es']) }}" class="aDrop">
         <img src="images/lang/flag-es.png" />
         <span class="marDrop">Español</span>
       </a>
     </li>
     <li class="padDrop">
       <a href="{{ url('lang', ['en']) }}" class="aDrop">
         <img src="images/lang/flag-uk.png" />
         <span class="marDrop">English</span>
       </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Buenas! solo me salen ..... poniendo esto. Tengo que hacer algo más?

Comment: pon en los puntos suspensivos el codigo que falta, lo puse asi para que veas con mas facilidad el nuevo if que puse

Comment: si perdona mi torpeza jajajaj, ya lo vi justo cuando te escribi. Gracias funciona perfecto, es mi primera vez en laravel y es un mundo esto

Comment: ok no hay problema, saludos!